# Why can't I use this transferEther function to send Ether to the smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have this code I have entered into Remix IDE, as ReceivedEther.sol, a standalone smart contract.

I've transferred 0.02 Ether to the smart contract, using MetaMask.

When I checked the smart contract's balance, it returns 200000000000000000, as expected.

If I try to use the transferEther function, however, and enter a number smaller than this - say, 0.005 ETH, or 50000000000000000 as the amount - it doesn't work using MetaMask.

When MetaMask prompts me it's never for that amount. It's for 0 ETH and 0.00322 gas fee (or whatever the gas is). Basically it always set the amount of ETH at 0 and only charges the fee.

Why can't I transfer an amount of ETH using this function in the Remix IDE with MetaMask?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract ReceivedEther {

    function transferEther(address payable _recipient, uint _amount) external returns (bool) {
        require(address(this).balance >= _amount, 'Not enough Ether in contract!');
        _recipient.transfer(_amount);
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
    * @return contract balance
    */
    function contractBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code sends ETH (stated in the `_amount` variable) **from the smart contract** to the `_recipient`. So it doesn't require any ETH to be sent in order to execute the `transferEther()` function.

---

If you want your contract to accept ETH, the function that accepts it (or the general `fallback()` or `receive()` function) needs to be marked as `payable`.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ReceivedEther {

    receive() external payable {} // note the `payable` keyword

    // rest of your implementation
}
```

Then you can send whathever amount of ETH to the smart contract address (without specifying any function to execute).

See more at https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/contracts.html#receive-ether-function

---

If you want to prefill the amount in MetaMask from Remix IDE, you can use the "Value" input in the "Deploy & Run Transactions" tab.